# django docker-compose failed can't find static

Tags: node.js, django, docker, nginx

So this is my backend Dockerfile it can't find backend/static what is wrong here?

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt -r requirements.txt
COPY scripts/start*.sh /
ADD . /app/
CMD ["python3", "backend/manage.py", "collectstatic", "--no-input"]
CMD ["python3", "backend/manage.py", "makemigrations"]
CMD ["python3", "backend/manage.py", "migrate", "--no-input"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "backend.wsgi", "-b", "0.0.0.0:7000"]
```

and this is my frontend Dockerfile

```
# build stage
FROM node:14.3.0-alpine3.10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app/
COPY frontend/package.json /app/
RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm install
COPY frontend /app/
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.17.10-alpine as production-stage
COPY nginx/prod/prod.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY backend/static /usr/src/app/static/
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /dist/
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

if you need more info(docker-compose file): https://github.com/Kenan7/djangorf-vue-ecommerce/tree/gcloud

ALSO, does GCP support docker-compose.yml file? if not what do I convert it into?

Comment: Only the last `CMD` has an effect.  (The container only runs one command, and each `CMD` line resets what that command is.)